# Invalid Host header on Ubuntu 18.04 running Apache2

Tags: linux, ssl, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

This is driving me *insane*!!

I'm running a web server on Ubuntu 18.04, and using plain ol Apache2. I've done countless searches and it all points to servers running other platforms, never the basic Apache2 system.

I have been trying to get the websites on my server going (*virtual hosts*) and have been having nothing but trouble getting each one to show when typing the url.

Anyway, I've been doing some tweaking here and there going by other suggestions here, and unfortunately, haven't kept track of what I have done. My memory is horrible due to some old man conditions I have, so I just can't remember where it all went wrong.

Here's what's happening:

All of my sites had been going to the same page on my server. But now, every site just brings up a blank page with

> Invalid Host header

at the top left of the page.

That's it! I have gone through every error log on my system to no avail. All of the logs are showing the basics.

Here's the last line or two of each:

**access.log:** `192.168.86.1 - - [07/Jan/2022:08:39:33 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 447 "http://jonezhost.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"`

**error.log:**
`[Sat Jan 15 07:28:57.253840 2022] [mpm_prefork:info] [pid 23104] AH00164: Server built: 2022-01-05T14:50:41`
`[Sat Jan 15 07:28:57.253847 2022] [core:notice] [pid 23104] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`
`[Sat Jan 15 07:51:10.359888 2022] [core:info] [pid 23104] AH00096: removed PID file /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid (pid=23104)`
`[Sat Jan 15 07:51:10.359916 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23104] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down`
`[Sat Jan 15 07:52:22.983318 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1458] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations`

**other_vhosts_access.log:**
`jonez.co:80 192.168.86.1 - - [13/Jan/2022:16:26:40 -0700] "GET /icons/folder.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 491 "http://24.51.60.170/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15"`
`jonez.co:80 192.168.86.1 - - [13/Jan/2022:16:26:58 -0700] "GET /html/ HTTP/1.1" 200 447 "http://24.51.60.170/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15"`
`jonez.co:80 87.251.64.141 - - [13/Jan/2022:16:38:03 -0700] "\x03" 400 497 "-" "-"`

That's...it! The system logs aren't showing anything Apache based.

The only thing I can figure out that's remotely close is it's trying to run in SSL, and I don't have SSL set up yet.

So I'm clueless! And ***ANY*** help would be **HUGELY** appreciated!!! I'm disabled and unable to leave home most of the time, so this is all I got to keep me busy. It's just a hobby, but an important one to me.

Thanks!!!

Comment: "Invalid Host header" means that the client is accessing the host with a different name than configured on the host. Like having configured the server as foo.example but accessing it as `http://bar.example`.

Comment: Whoa! Don’t tell me that’s it! I have spent a week of brainstorming trying to figure this out, and it resides in one simple issue; the url being sent, which translates to an IP Address, but still carry’s the url, which is read by the server and sent to the corresponding virtual host. But, somewhere along the line, that url is being misread somewhere. Which is where my confusion lies.

Comment: aaaaaand you were correct sir! Turned out to be an IP address issue! Just as you said, the client was accessing the host with a different IP than what was configured on the host.

Your answer really got me moving on it and I figured it out! I explained the details below. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*FIXED IT!!! lol*

Turns out the problem wasn't with my server at all. It was my router's port forwarding!

I use Google Home stuff and Google Wi-Fi points. I don't recall their names atm, but they're Google. (*Probably a red flag right there! lol*)

Anyway, I have two IP Addresses on my server (*I'm not doing any mail or dns stuff, so really just need one*). I had them both pointing towards different websites. And herein lies the issue.

My main IP for the server was 192.XXX.XXX.200, and the second was 192.XXX.XXX.202. But I wasn't pointing them correctly. They both needed to point to port 80. I had .200 pointing to 80 and .202 pointing to 8080. So there was some confusion when setting up my virtual hosts. Something happened, I don't remember what, that made me decide to use .202 as the primary IP for vHosts. Then in my `/etc/hosts` file, I used both IP's going to the same location - let's say example.com.

So, all I can think of is that the sites weren't seeing the .202 and using the .200 since it was first on the list. And the "*Invalid Host Header*" was showing up due to the IP address confusion.

So, I just removed the .200 from all the settings, removed the port forwarding for it and set .202 to use ports 80 and 8080, 10000 for Webmin (*cool little script if you want to monitor things away from home*), 25, yadda. The sites came right up!

I still have some cleaning up to do with everything that I have tried, but at least **THAT** issue is done and gone! And I also know that "*Invalid Host Header*" will come up for many reasons depending on the platform you are using. So this is just one thing for people to check when frantically trying to get their websites back up!

Thanks for all the responses with great help!